# css transform doesn't work on css generated content for ::after, ::before elements

Tags: css, css-transforms

http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/enmxu/

```
<a href="#">Inbox</a>

a { text-decoration: none; }
a::after { content: ' ⇧'; transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

According to this site, it was fixed in Chrome 23...but I have Chrome 28 and it doesn't work.

http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/
http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

Comment: You've linked to documents talking about animations and transitions on pseudo elements - that has nothing to do with transforms.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I got a bit curious about this myself, so I looked a bit further into it.  Turns out, it does work.

After looking at the test case: [pseudo-transition.html](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/LayoutTests/fast/css-generated-content/pseudo-transition.html?rev=138632)

I noticed the pseudo element had a style of: `display: block`.

Changing your fiddle to use `display: inline-block` and voila!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enmxu/2/)

And with an onLoad transition:

[Transition Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enmxu/3/)

New Style:

```
a:after { display: inline-block; content: ' ⇧'; -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#definitions):

> A transformable element is an element in the HTML namespace which is either a **block-level or atomic inline-level element**, or whose ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’, ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or ‘table-caption’; or an element in the SVG namespace (see [SVG11]) which has the attributes ‘transform’, ‘patternTransform’ or ‘gradientTransform’.

Hence you need to specify `display: block` or `display: inline-block` (or, say, `display: table-row`) to your element or pseudo-element in order for the transform to be applied.